# Haskell - implement powerset function of a set

Tags: haskell, powerset

I've just started to learn Haskell and had difficult times of solving this problem:
`powerSet :: Set a -> Set (Set a)`

Here's my attempt:

```
powerSet :: Tree a -> Tree (Tree a)
powerSet Empty = Empty
powerSet tree = fromList' [fromList' p | p <- powerSet' (toList tree)]

powerSet' :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerSet' [] = [[]]
powerSet' (x:xs) = [x:ps | ps <- powerSet' xs] ++ powerSet' xs
```

I should expect the output in such order: `powerset {1,2,3} => { {}, {1}, {2}, {1,2,3}, {1,3}, {2}, {2,3}, {3} }`

But instead I got this: `powerset {1,2,3} => { {1,2,3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1}, {2,3}, {2}, {3}, {} }`

Is there any way I can change it?

Comment: Why do you expect the order to be `{ {}, {1}, ... }`?

Comment: A set is an unordered collection. Likely, you should disregard the order of the elements as they are printed.

Comment: Your implementation furthermore deals with a `Tree`, instead of a `Set`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem For what it's worth, if you change the first `{2}` to `{1,2}` in the expected output, then the subsets appear in lexicographical order; so perhaps the exercise is intended to encourage a search tree implementation.

Comment: @DanielWagner: ah yes. But then the `fromList` should thus insert the items in a ordered way. Then the "responsibility" is more for the tree generation part than for the `powerSet'` function.

Answer (score 0):

> Wondering if there's any way I can change it?

Well the order is `{ {1,2,3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {2}, {3}, {} }` because that is how you implemented this. Indeed for an empty list, you return as `powerSet' []`, a singleton list with an empty list. For a non-empty list, you recurse on the tail of the list, and first you yield that list where you each time prepend `x` to that list, and then you yield the result of the recursive call without prepending.

Hence for a list `[2]`, the recursive case is `[[]]`, so we first prepend it with `2` yielding `[2]`, and then we do not prepend this, yielding `[]`.

If we thus calculate the powerset of `[1,2]`, the recursive call will result in `[[2], []]`. We first emit the list where we each time prepend `1`, so `[1,2]` and `[1]`, and then we emit the list without prepending, making it `[2]` and `[]`. Or putting this together `[[1,2], [1], [2], []]`.

You can yield the results in a different order, for example with:

```
powerSet' :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerSet' l = [] : go l
    where go [] = []
          go (x:xs) = [x] : map (x:) (go xs) ++ go xs
```

But as [@DanielWagner says in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742656/haskell-implement-powerset-function-of-a-set#comment105634404_59742656):

> so perhaps the exercise is intended to encourage a search tree implementation.

You likely should not alter the order of the items that are yielded by the `powerSet'`, but make sure your `Tree` is a *(binary) search tree*, and thus implement the `fromList` function in such way that it insert the items in an ordered manner in your `Tree`.

Comment: yes I did use a BST and this explained my question very clearly. Many thanks!